# Docker Volume Empty

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to go through the [Docker Tutorial](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume-def) and mount a volume to my host OS, as in

```
$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

I'm trying to mount a directory from my host OS (OSX) to the VM:

```
$  docker run -P  --name web -v /Users/simon/source/test:/opt/test training/webapp ls -al /opt/test
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Jun 27 17:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 27 17:51 ..
$
```

But from the host OS:

```
$ ls -al /Users/simon/source/test
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 simon  staff   102 Jun 27 10:55 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 36 simon  staff  1224 Jun 27 10:55 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 simon  staff     0 Jun 27 10:55 foo
$
```

Perhaps related - my understanding is that docker volumes are supposed to be stored in `/var/lib/docker`, which doesn't exist for me:

```
$ ls -al /var/lib/docker
ls: /var/lib/docker: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker server does not work on darwin. That's why you use the VM. When you use `-v`, you actually send the command to the docker server running on the vm. The path you send or relative to the server, not the client. `/var/lib/docker` is present on the VM, not the host. The empty volume you see is the expected behavior as it mounts `/Users/simon/source/test` from the VM which does not exists, therefor gets created by docker and is empty.

In order to achieve what you are trying to do, either move to the VM or setup shared directories or even better, do not use bind-mounts. See Dockerfile's `ADD` as an alternative.

Comment: I was missing one very very important thing: Docker is running inside of VirtualBox on my Mac! Thanks for point this out, this made all the sense in the world after.

Comment: As of [Docker 1.3](http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/), this should now work as expected.